# Run thousands of commands sequentially

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, matlab

I have a task now to run some thousand of commands sequentially. The commands are all in the form `$ /home/user/.lcmodel/bin/lcmodel < 2HzSNR100C2.5.txt`.
Only the numbers (in **bold** type) are different from file to file. The numbers are generated from a `for` loop in MatLab.

For example, number before `Hz` will be `2` and `3`, the number after `SNR` will be `100` and `200`, numbers after `C` will be `2.5`, `3` and `3.5`. In this case, I have to run 12 of this kind of commands. And yes, I only need to run them as single lines, the detailed codes are already stored in the txt files.

I am completely new to Linux, can someone help me to write a file or command to run these thousands of commands sequentially and automatically?

Comment: Please edit your question with a few details: How are those numbers changed? Is it relevant to have a special order for the commands? Are those files alone in a dedicated directory?

Comment: Sorry, for example, number before Hz will be 2 and 3, number after SNR will be 100 and 200, numbers after C will be 2.5, 3 and 3.5. In this case, I have to run 12 this kind of commands. And yes, I only need to run them as single lines, the detailed codes are already stored in the txt files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: use a loop. for i in *.txt ... /path/to/lcmodel $i ... done use find to identify the files if needed. Without a little more detail I can only make suggestions. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all the files are in the current working directory (i.e. none is nested in some subdirectory), use a `bash` `for` loop (thanks to Incnis Mrsi for the tighter globbing pattern):

```
for f in ?HzSNR???C*.txt; do /home/user/.lcmodel/bin/lcmodel < "$f"; done
```

This specific globbing pattern is pretty tight; also using globbing itself will result in the ordered list of the files in the current working directory to be expanded in the `for` statement, resulting, ultimately, in the files being processed in their numerical order;

If not all the files are in the current working directory, use find:

```
find . -type f -name '?HzSNR???C*.txt' -exec /home/user/.lcmodel/bin/lcmodel < {} \;
```

However using `find` in general does not guarantee that the files will be processed in their numerical order; if processing them in their numerical order is mandatory, use `find` + `sort` + `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '?HzSNR???C*.txt' | sort | xargs -I file /home/user/.lcmodel/bin/lcmodel < file
```

Comment: @CharlieSo Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Good one :) that's a +1

Comment: `*` is unsafe. Whenever possible, use `?` for exactly *one* character, `??` for exactly two, etc.

Comment: The `for` solution will blow up if the number of files is too large.  The `find` solutions should work with any number of files.

Comment: @chicks Indeed, pointed that out and added an alternative solution using `find`. Thanks

Comment: @chicks why would you think that the `for` solution will blow up ? its dealing with a single file at a time.. there could be an issue with available memory but thats practically non-existent now a days given the size of RAM a home computer has..anyway the point is it will have no impact on `ARG_MAX`, will work just fine..

Comment: @heemayl Why do you think that `ARG_MAX` doesn't impact the `for` loop? Honestly I don't have a comprehensive understanding of the thing since I'm missing bits but according to what I have read around that threshold should apply to anything run in a command-line (i.e. also trascending `bash` and any shell in general). Is this inexact?

Comment: kos, IFAIU `ARG_MAX` has an impact any command and its associated arguments..for example if you run `rm *`..if you have milions of files to remove it would invoke `ARG_MAX` in the process which is one-fourth of the stack size..`2097152` on my system..now if you run `for i in *; do rm "$i"; done` you are dealing with a single file as far as `rm` is concerned..so you would be safe..

Comment: @heymayl you are correct for the `rm`, but the `for` is a command that is effected by `ARG_MAX` also, so you are limited in the number of files or more exactly the number of characters in the filenames which effectively limits the number of files.  `find` is your odd but helpful friend.

Comment: @heemayl ^^ That's what I meant either, the problem I see is that the `for` statement could break due to the globbing expansion, not the stuff inside referencing `$f`

Comment: @chicks Thats not correct, those files found after glob expansion are not arguments to `for`, for will deal with them individually eventually as the expansion is done by shell itself (and `for` in a built-in)..have a test, at first try `touch {1..1000000}`, then `for i in {1..1000000}; do touch "$i"; done`..in the first case you should get `bash: /usr/bin/touch: Argument list too long`, in the second case the million files should be created..

Comment: @heemayl Well you're indeed right, didn't know about this. Thanks! Rolling back

Comment: kos, don't roll back everything, its a very well written answer once again..just remove the part cursing cute `for` :)

Comment: @heemayl Yes that's what I meant actually :) thanks!

Comment: kos, you got my upvote now :)